# Why is the web worker api not working in react even in the simplest implementation?

Tags: fetch-api, web-worker, mern

I created a toy mern app which can upload images to mongodb. It works fine in the development but after I deploy to heroku, I get a timeout error. After doing a fair amount of investigations I come to the conclusion that web workers will help sort this out. So I've done this:

*This is a snippet from the component that takes care of sending this request, to upload an image:*

```
const handleUploadPhoto = evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        const worker = new Worker('imageUpload.js');
        worker.postMessage(selectedPhotos);

        worker.onmessage = evt => console.log(evt.data);

        closeModal();
    };
```

This whole component is actually a modal, and after I submit this `handleUploadPhoto` function the modal closes. Notice the `closeModal` function;

*In the same folder as this component I have the `imageUpload.js` worker file:*

```
self.addEventListener('message', evt => {
    const { selectedPhotos } = evt.data;

    selectedPhotos.map(photo => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('photo', photo);

            fetch( `/api/photo/upload/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'))._id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                headers: ['Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'],
            }).then(() => console.log('OK'));
        });

    self.postMessage(evt.data);
});
```

The idea behind this functionality is that I select one or more images, then I map through them and send a post request to the server with each image as formData. So I thought to move the request to a worker so that it doesn't break my UI anymore. Needless to say that it doesn't work and it gives `net::EMPTY_RESPONSE` error after some seconds. What I also noticed is that the worker doesn't communicate with the file it was issued in at all. I tried to make a text message pop in the console:

const handleUploadPhoto = evt => {
evt.preventDefault();

```
        const worker = new Worker('imageUpload.js');
        worker.postMessage('Hello');

        worker.onmessage = evt => console.log(evt.data);

        closeModal();
    };
```

*In the same folder as this component I have the `imageUpload.js` worker file:*

```
self.addEventListener('message', evt => {
    self.postMessage(evt.data + ' world');
});
```

It doesn't work. I tried the same approach in a separate project and it worked.
How can I make an HTTP request do what it's supposed to do from a web worker?